# Why can I sometimes not launch Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm currently doing a project in Jupyter Notebook. I just re-installed the latest version of Anaconda, and I wanted to launch it using cmd as administrator (note that I activated virtual environment first).

The weird thing is that sometimes either it shows a typical jupyter notebook layout, or it just shows this screen:

[image: This is the message.]

I installed Anaconda in `D:\ancd`.

Here is also my environment paths

[image: environment paths]

Why does this happen?

Comment: The error is quite clear about what happened - the connection was reset. Did you try checking the connection, checking the proxy and the firewall, or running Windows network diagnostics?

Comment: I ran Windows network diagnostics, and it said something like "The device or resource (127.0.0.1) is not set up to accept connections on port "8888""....

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a problem with your browser settings, you can try another browsers(mozilla, safari). I had a like problem, and I applied this solution.